# Using Zyxel Modem As A Simple Voip ATA Device

Tags: networking, router, modem, voip, sip

I have a Zyxel P-2602HWL modem/router which I want to use as a Voip ATA device only. In other words, I already have a router that I am using and I only want to use the Voip functionality of the Zyxel device.

To that end, I did the following configurations:

- Connected Zyxel to my computer via ethernet and changed its IP address to 192.168.1.10. And in the WAN ocnfiguration, I changed the mode from "Router" to "Bridged". (I am not sure if this was necessary though.)
- Disconnected Zyxel from my computer and connected it to my modem/router.
- Connected PSTN line to Zyxel and connected an analog phone to Zyxel's "Phone1" port.
- I assigned the number "100" to the "SIP1" profile, which is the profile for the "Phone1" port.

With this configuration, I was able to receieve PSTN calls to the analog phone without a problem.

But I was unable to make a SIP call from or to this phone. I tried calling it from a softphone on my PC, with the following url:

```
sip:100@192.168.1.10:5060
```

But it fails.

Then I tried calling the softphone from the analog phone. For that, I defined the PC's softphone url in the SpeedDial profile of Zyxel at #01, and then tried calling "#01" on the analog phone but to no avail.

As far as I understand, there seems to be a problem reaching the Zyxel device. When I query the 5060 udp port, it says "NOT LISTENING", whereas its web UI port 80 is in the LISTENING state.

I am not sure but I guess there needs to be an extra configuration made in order to use the Zyxel router not as a router but as a simple Voip device but I don't know what it is.

Any ideas?